# Developing on two different Mac's as a team member

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I have my personal developer account which I use to develop/test my own apps on my own Mac/ iPhone. Also, I've been added as a team member to another developer account so I can work on / test / develop apps for the client.

So basically, I want three things :

**1)** To develop my own apps and test them on my own iPhone while developing on my personal Mac (as an Agent).

**2)** To develop client's apps and test them on my own iPhone while developing on my personal Mac (as a member of other, client's team).

**3)** To develop client's apps and test them on my own iPhone, while developing on client's Mac (as a member of other, client's team).

Right now, if I switch team (say at home, on my own Mac), Xcode offers a help to fix the issue with certificates, and after that, I am able to run client's apps on my iPhone, but I am no longer able to run my own apps on that Mac. Also at this point I am not able to test client's apps on my own device when I develop on client's Mac.

Obviously, I am missing something here... How do I setup all this ? I guess this is possible and it is an usual situation.

EDIT:

After suggestions to export developer account from Mac that is working (currently that is client's computer), and import it on Mac which doesn't work (my own computer), I got this message:

[image: Error message]

Don't forget...I want to be able to run my own apps and clients apps on a single device (but to develop them on different Macs), and I want to be able to switch teams appropriately.

Comment: My first guess is that your developer certificate is being reacted when you activate it on the other machine. You my want to export you your client profile on the machine that work and import on the machine that does not work. You can export it via Xcode settings, by selecting the account and use the cog icon to export/import the settings.

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks for a quick response... Just to double-check... You say that I have to export developer account on client's Mac and import it at my own Mac ? It is a bit confusing, because right now, I can't run my own apps (on my device). Would I be able to run my own apps  as well (with my own team selected) after this exporting/importing ?

Comment: You should export the profile on the machine that works, so yes on your client machine. This will export the certificates need for development include the private key's.

Comment: Okay will try as soon as I get home. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @rckoenes I just tried what you said, and I got message from my edit :|

Comment: You should use the import profile, do not reset since this will invalidate the profile and create a new one.

Comment: @rckoenes It is weird. Even if I do that, I get the same message from the image above.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create certificate and profile from one mac - Revoke if already created.
   (add all required device id/UDID in which you wants to run your app).
2. Then install that certificate and profile in that particular mac in which you create certificate.
3. Now open key-chain access and export .p12 file of that certificate and install it(.p12 file) in other mac and also install profile.